# How to add a google business search to android app. New programmer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, kotlin

Hi there I have managed to make a basic android app with all sort of puppy information for new owners. It has all the categories you expect like training etc. However I want to add a more advanced feature that as a new programmer I have no idea how to do!

I want to make an activity in the app so when they click it, or maybe just enter their postcode it shows up the local dog groomers within 10 miles, or maybe the local vet practices within 10 miles etc.

I have no idea where to start with this. I am not looking for it to be handed to me on a plate but does anyone have any basic guidance as to where to start etc.

Comment: The google maps API might have such a feature, if you provide lattitude and longitude.

Comment: I'd start looking for the documentation of "google business search" in java. Then think about ways to get the required data (e.g. look at how to get the user location on an android phone) and how to use or display the data you can get out of the search. It's a big puzzle and you have to find creative ways to combine all the pieces

Comment: Since you say you are new, it may be useful to start with https://developers.google.com and https://developer.android.com/ to see what functionality is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use Google search, you can use the [Google Places Android SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro).  You will need to set up an API key.  It's free for non-enterprise usage.

Other companies also offer similar services, such as[Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/), though from personal experience, the search results are not nearly as accurate as the Google ones.